# Market Risk - credit v. equity

Tags: risk, derivatives, exposure

I am requesting language for the use of derivatives in a portfolio.  The goal is to allow the use of derivatives only in instances where the portfolio aggregate market risk exposure (post implementation of derivatives positions) is less than or equal to what is was before the implementation of derivatives.  Straight forward enough for single leg hedging.  However, how about in the instance where derivatives are used to express a short 1 of IG credit (CDX) and long 1 in equity futures?  This would result in more risk after the short credit/long equity derivative pairing?  Any/all thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Replace language by guidance?

Comment: Also begs a question of whether every derivative must be individually risk-reducing, versus any combination of them would qualify as such.

Comment: Thank you Bob and demully for responding.  Individual legs don't need to be risk-reducing.  The issue is that if I model portfolio vol w/ short IG and long Equity, the risk of the portfolio increases.